# Qemu: booting failed

Tags: assembly, nasm, qemu, boot, osdev

I started making an OS entirely in assembly (by my choice) but when you run it it doesn't work.

There are the files..

bootloader.asm:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
    cli
        
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
        
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x9000

    mov bx, 0x8000
    mov dh, 1
    mov dl, 0   
    mov ch, 0   
    mov cl, 2
    mov ah, 2   
    int 0x13    
        
    jmp 0x8000

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

kernel.asm:

```
section .text
global _start_kernel

_start_kernel:
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov al, 'H'    
    int 0x10       
    
    mov al, 'e'
    int 0x10
    
    mov al, 'l'
    int 0x10
    
    mov al, 'l'
    int 0x10
    
    mov al, 'o'
    int 0x10

    hlt

times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

linker.ld

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7c00;

    bootloader :
    {
        bootloader.o (.text);
    }

    kernel :
    {
        kernel.o (.text);
    }

    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.bss*);
        *(COMMON*);
    }
}
```

Makefile:

```
boot = bootloader.asm
kernel = kernel.asm

boot_o = bootloader.o
kernel_o = kernel.o

os = os.bin

asm_compiler = nasm

compile:
    $(asm_compiler) -f elf32 -g $(boot) -o $(boot_o)
    $(asm_compiler) -f elf32 -g $(kernel) -o $(kernel_o)
    ld -m elf_i386 -nmagic -T linker.ld -o $(os) $(boot_o) $(kernel_o)

run:
    qemu-system-i386 -fda $(os)

clean:
    rm $(boot_o) $(kernel_o) $(os)
```

When I run qemu, it says boot failed, the result should read hello world, but nothing is displayed

ps. I'm a beginner and I'm not very good at it yet

Comment: First problem is that you are outputting an ELF file instead of a binary. In `linker.ld` add `OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)`. In `bootloader.asm` and `kernel.asm` you need to put `bits 16` at the top because `-felf32` defaults to `bits 32`. This will build 2 sectors one after another `os.bin`, so in `bootloader.asm` change both occurrences of 0x8000 to 0x7e00. In `bootloader.asm` change `mov dh, 1` to `mov dh, 0` since you want to read from cylinder 0. You also need to set `AL` to the number of sectors to read. To read 1 add `mov al, 1`. I recommend commenting oh `mov dl, 0` since BIOS will set `dl`

Comment: @MichaelPetch bootloader.asm:2: error: parser: instruction expected

bootloader.asm:
`org 0x7c00`
`use 16`

`section .text`
`global _start`

`_start:`
    `cli`
        
    `xor ax, ax`
    `mov ds, ax`
    `mov es, ax`
        
    `mov ss, ax`
    `mov sp, 0x9000`

    `mov bx, 0x7e00`
    `mov dh, 0`
    `mov dl, 0`   
    `mov ch, 0`  
    `mov cl, 2`
    `mov ah, 2`   
    `int 0x13`    
        
    `jmp 0x7e00`

`times 510-($-$$) db 0`
`dw 0xAA55`

Comment: The code you posted in your question doesn't use `org`. `org` isn't allowed when you assemble to `elf32`. `org` is supported if you use `-f bin`. The `org` is actually driven by your linker script. Remove the `org 0x7c00`. As well the code in your comment doesn't set `al` with the number of sectors to read.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I fix it, but now i have error with the output extensions in the ld file, may be that I have to change the emulation of the command: ld -m elf_i386 -nmagic -T linker.ld -o $(os) $(boot_o) $(kernel_o)?
the Makefile is:
`boot_o = bootloader.bin`
`kernel_o = kernel.bin`
`os = os.bin`
`compile:`
 `nasm -f bin -g bootloader.asm -o $(boot_o)`
 `nasm -f bin -g kernel.asm -o $(kernel_o)`
 `ld -m elf_i386 -nmagic -T linker.ld -o $(os) $(boot_o) $(kernel_o)`

this is the error: bootloader.bin: file not recognized: file format not recognized

Comment: Don't use `-f bin` with NASM (in your case). Use `-felf32` and remove `org` statements from your asm files. When using `-felf32` the org point is determined by the linker script at link time. I don't know why you are using `org` as your original question didn't use them and I never told you to use them.

Comment: @MichaelPetch sorry for the error, now the boot works, but the string hello world doesn't print, i'm using qemu-system-i386

Comment: In your bootloader did you add a `mov al, 1` to tell int 0x13/AH=2 to read 1 sector (you can set `AL` to read more as well). As it is you set `AL` to 0 by zeroing `AX`. Loading zero sectors obviously doesn't read anything from the disk.